# Dependant dropdown list does not show options

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-2

Following code developed to create four dependent dropdownlist using codeigniter. Four dropdown list are used to select Client Name, project, task and task cost respectively. But only options for first three dropdown list are fetched from database. Options for the third dropdown list do not fetch from database.Also no error isshown in console log
**Controller**

```
<?php
ob_start();
// security first always....
(defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed'));
/**
 * Class Controller
 *
 * Class Dropdown Controller to handle login & logout
 */
class Dropdown extends CI_controller
{
    /**
     * Class Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // execute parent class constructor
        parent::__construct();
        // load model
        $this->load->model('Dropdown_model');
    }

    /**
     * Default method to execute if method name missing
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function index(){
  $array_data = array();
  // only on Ajax Request
  if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
      // if request for projects
      if ($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == 'project') {
          // get client name
          $client     = $this->input->post('client', true);
          // get project data by client name
          $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(trim($client), 'project');
          // AjaxPOST JSON response
          //set page header json type
          $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
          $this->output->set_output(json_encode($array_data));
      }
      // if request for task
      else if ($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == 'task') {
          // get project name
          $project    = $this->input->post('project', true);
          // get task data by project
          $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(trim($project), 'task');
          // AjaxPOST JSON response
          //echo json_encode($array_data);die();
          //set page header type json
          $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
          $this->output->set_output(json_encode($array_data));
      }
      else if ($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == 'taskcost') {
          // get project name
          $task    = $this->input->post('task', true);
          // get task data by project
          $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(trim($task), 'taskcost');
          // AjaxPOST JSON response
          //echo json_encode($array_data);die();
          //set page header type json
          $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
          $this->output->set_output(json_encode($array_data));
      }
  }else{
    //put all view part in else
    // else get all client data
    $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(null, null);
    // send to view
    $this->load->view('dropdown', ['data' => $array_data]);
  }

}
}
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php
// No direct script execution
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Class Dropdown_model to handle all related information from MySQL
 */
class Dropdown_model extends CI_Model
{
    /**
     * MySQL table which contains all data about users
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'task';
    /**
     * Returns, User First Name by Email ID
     * @param  [type] $email_addres   [description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function get_dropdown_data($where_data = null, $type = null)
    {
        $query = '';

        // clients only
        if (is_null($type) && is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('cname');
            // only unique clients
            $this->db->distinct('cname');
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }

        // projects by client
        elseif ($type == 'project' && !is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('projectname');
            // where clause
            $this->db->where('cname', $where_data);
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }

        // task by project
        elseif ($type == 'task' && !is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('task');
            // where clause
            $this->db->where('projectname', $where_data);
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }
        // task by project
        elseif ($type == 'taskcost' && !is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('taskcost');
            // where clause
            $this->db->where('task', $where_data);
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }

        // if record exist
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            // return all data as array
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            // error
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CodeIgniter: Dependent dropdown list by using single table value</title>
    <!-- load bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- load jquery library -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- load bootstrap js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Client</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="clients" name="clients">
                <option value="0">--Select Clients--</option>
                <?php if (isset($data)):?>
                    <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value): ?>
                        <option value="<?=$value['cname']?>"><?=$value['cname']?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Projects</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="projects" name="projects">
                <option value="0">--Select Projects--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Tasks</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="tasks" name="tasks">
                <option value="0">--Select Tasks--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Tasks</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="taskcost" name="taskcost">
                <option value="0">--Select Tasks--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // client select box
    var client     = $('select#clients');
    // project select box
    var projects   = $('select#projects');
    // task select box
    var tasks      = $('select#tasks');
    var taskcost      = $('select#taskcost');
    // on change client name, get projects
    client.on('change', function () {
        // get selected client name
        var client_val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        // post data with CSRF token
        var data = {
            action:'project',
            client: client_val,
            "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
        };
        // AjaxPOST to get projects
        $.post('.', data, function(json) {
            var projects_data = '<option value="0">--Select Projects--</option>';
            $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                projects_data += '<option value="'+obj.projectname+'">'+obj.projectname+'</option>';
            });
            // append all projects in project dropdown
            projects.html(projects_data);
        }, 'JSON');
    });
    // on change project, get task
    projects.on('change', function () {
        // get selected project name
        var project = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        // AjaxPOSt wit CSRF
        var data = {
            action:'task',
            project: project,
            "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
        };
        $.post('.', data, function(json) {
            var task_data = '<option value="0">--Select Task--</option>';
            $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                task_data += '<option value="'+obj.task+'">'+obj.task+'</option>';
            });
            // append all task data in Task dropdown
            tasks.html(task_data);
        }, 'JSON');
        taskcost.on('change', function () {
        // get selected project name
        var tasks = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        // AjaxPOSt wit CSRF
        var data = {
            action:'taskcost',
            tasks: tasks,
            "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
        };
        $.post('.', data, function(json) {
            var taskcost_data = '<option value="0">--Select Task--</option>';
            $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                taskcost_data += '<option value="'+obj.taskcost+'">'+obj.taskcost+'</option>';
            });
            // append all task data in Task dropdown
            tasks.html(taskcost_data);
        }, 'JSON');
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the error message (if any) or any exception (if any) which is showed in developer tools.

Comment: This is the error shows in console log.."Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input index:110"

Comment: Closing of `projects.on` method was missing, full js added in answer. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your JS. A closing of `projects.on` function was missing, added it. Rectified code is as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // client select box
    var client     = $('select#clients');
    // project select box
    var projects   = $('select#projects');
    // task select box
    var tasks      = $('select#tasks');
    var taskcost      = $('select#taskcost');
    // on change client name, get projects
    client.on('change', function () {
        // get selected client name
        var client_val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        // post data with CSRF token
        var data = {
            action:'project',
            client: client_val,
            "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
        };
        // AjaxPOST to get projects
        $.post('.', data, function(json) {
            var projects_data = '<option value="0">--Select Projects--</option>';
            $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                projects_data += '<option value="'+obj.projectname+'">'+obj.projectname+'</option>';
            });
            // append all projects in project dropdown
            projects.html(projects_data);
        }, 'JSON');
    });
    // on change project, get task
    projects.on('change', function () {
        // get selected project name
        var project = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        // AjaxPOSt wit CSRF
        var data = {
            action:'task',
            project: project,
            "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
        };
        $.post('.', data, function(json) {
            var task_data = '<option value="0">--Select Task--</option>';
            $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                task_data += '<option value="'+obj.task+'">'+obj.task+'</option>';
            });
            // append all task data in Task dropdown
            tasks.html(task_data);
            }, 'JSON');
        });
        taskcost.on('change', function () {
        // get selected project name
        var tasks = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        // AjaxPOSt wit CSRF
        var data = {
            action:'taskcost',
            tasks: tasks,
            "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
        };
        $.post('.', data, function(json) {
            var taskcost_data = '<option value="0">--Select Task--</option>';
            $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                taskcost_data += '<option value="'+obj.taskcost+'">'+obj.taskcost+'</option>';
            });
            // append all task data in Task dropdown
            tasks.html(taskcost_data);
        }, 'JSON');
    });
  });
```

Please confirm the above code.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr.Girish. But still options for the task cost deos not show in the dropdown list.

Comment: Just check any more error or exception in console or network tab of developer toolbar. From network tab, click on the request which is triggered as you change the value of your first select box. After clicking, check the "Request" and "Response" tab so you can confirm is data to be send and to be receive is correct or not.